# GetOpenFilename not opening file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have got this code:

```
Sub openMyStatsData()

Dim myFileName As Variant

myFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename '(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx*;*.xlsm*")

If fileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open (myFileName)
End If

End Sub
```

the dialog window opens and it let me browse and choose the file i want but when i click on the Open button nothing else happens. i need to be able to browse for the file and open it.

I am new to VBA in case you were wondering. thanks!

Comment: State 'Option Explicit' at the top of your module (before the rest of the code) and see if you can work it out from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this one:

```
Sub openMyStatsData()

Dim myFileName As Variant

myFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename '(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx*;*.xlsm*")

If myFileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open (myFileName)
End If

End Sub
```

And make sure that you always have [Option Explicit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=option%20explicit%20vba) on top, to avoid errors like this one.

Answer (score 2):

You'd called the variable "myFileName" but then in the If statement you wrote "fileName". You have to change it to "myFileName".